# Delete data with checkbox in a table

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, checkbox

I display a table on the website after a select option (I use ajax) and get the datas from the database. What I want to do is to insert a checkbox in my table and when it is checked delete the row in the database. I don't want to use a submit button but only the checkbox to delete it.

I'm not really good with ajax and JavaScript. This is the code:

The select :

```
<p>
            <label for="client">Veuillez choisir le fournisseur :</label><br />
               <select name="client" id="client" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
                    <?php 
                        // echo '<option value=""/></option>';
                        while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
                        {               
                            echo '<option value='.$donnees['refCustomer'].'>'.$donnees['legalCompanyName'].' </option>';                                
                            //$value = $donnees['refCustomer'];                     
                        }


                        $reponse->closeCursor();
                    ?>              
               </select>
            </p>
```

The script :

```
    <script>
    function showUser(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else { 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","getTableBuffer.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
    </script>
```

getTableBuffer.php :

```
    <?php
    $q = intval($_GET['q']);

    try
    {
        $bdd = new PDO());
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
            die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    $reponse = $bdd->query('select * from vendor_'.$q.'_offers_ncli_amendments_buffer');


    echo '<table class="imagetable">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>code</th>';
    echo '<th>dateAdded</th>';
    echo '<th>effectiveDate</th>';
    echo '<th>price</th>';
    echo '<th>type</th>';
    echo '<th>destination</th>';
    echo '</tr>';

    while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
    {       
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="code" id="code" value="'.$donnees['code'].'"/>'.$donnees['code'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$donnees['dateAdded'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$donnees['effectiveDate'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$donnees['price'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$donnees['type'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$donnees['destination'].'</td>';
        echo "</tr>";           

    }

    echo "</table>";
    echo "</br>";
    echo "</br>";
    $reponse->closeCursor();
    ?>
```

Comment: I don't see `DELETE FROM table...` anywhere.

Comment: I dont know how to get the value and delete it

Comment: You really should look into [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com) and event handlers. Try a `click` handler and use the `.val()` function to get the value of the checkbox you clicked, then user `.ajax()` to create a post to a PHP file, that deletes that item.

Comment: Hopefully you are a student and this is not a live app? Please look up String Escaping and sanitizing as currently your code is vulnerable to a number of attacks (SQL Injection, XSS, CSRF) because of the way you are using string variables everywhere with no parameters or sanitization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add event `onclick` to your checkbox :

   ```
   echo '<td><input onclick="remove(this);" type="checkbox" name="code" id="code" ....';
   ```
2. create function `remove()` in you javascript, that send the `$donnees['code']` to a `remove.php` to delete it from DB :

   ```
   function remove(e)
   {
       if (e.target.checked) 
       { 
           ....
           xmlhttp.open("GET","remove.php?code="+e.target.value,true);
           xmlhttp.send();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create `remove.php` that get the code and delete from DB :

   ```
   <?php
        if(isset($_GET['code'])){
             //Query to remove from DB where code = $_GET['code']
        }
   ?>
   ```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Is it possible to do an ajax function in another? what I mean is I display my table using ajax and to delete elements I have to insert checkbox in the table which use ajax aswell? Im sorry im new with the javascript and ajax stuffs

Comment: I can see that you have already checkbox inside the `getTableBuffer.php` called by ajax : `....<td><input type="checkbox" name="code" id="code" value="'.$donnees['code'].'"/>'.$donnees['code'].'</td>';......
        `

Comment: yes and now it is : echo '<td><input onclick="remove(this.value)" type="checkbox" name="code" id="code" value="'.$donnees['code'].'"/>'.$donnees['code'].'</td>';

Comment: "to delete elements I have to insert checkbox in the table" you have already checkbox inside the table so just attach click event to checkbox and create function remove + php file remove like mentioned in answer and it should work (you don't have to do an ajax function in another).

Comment: Ok it works thank you! I added the remove function to the checkbox : echo '<td><input type="checkbox"  onclick="remove(this)" name="code" id="code" value="'.$donnees['code'].'"/>'.$donnees['code'].'</td>';                          Added the function remove() and im my remove.php I delete the row